# How to multiply all elements from array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I am beginning to learn C# and am writing a program that will first ask a user to enter a list of numbers. When the user finishes entering the input, I would like to square every number the user provided in the input. An example of user input is `2 3 5`.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Program
{
    class Third
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter how much numbers");

            int howMuch = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] num = new int[howMuch];
            int sum = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++ )
            {
                sum = num[i] * num[i]; // this is what i did but it does not work?
            }

            Console.WriteLine(sum);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Specifically, I would first like the user input to be captured in the `numbers` array. And then I would like to square each number in the `num` array that was created. What's wrong with my program?

Comment: try **sum+= num[i] * num[i]**

Comment: Please provide the output of the program, and the desired output if it is possible.

Comment: you are not filing in any values in the array. You just create an array of Length = howMuch but you have to also fill values in it

Comment: There are multiple things wrong with your example that Im not sure  where to begin... i think for a start you want to do `sum = sum * num[i];` but then you start `i` as 0 so the sum will be zero

Comment: @FilipJava, are you trying to do a factorial? or a sum of your numbers? or a sum of the numbers entered squared? could you please clarify what you want to happen?

Comment: Guys i fixed it thank you all i will +1 all, the thing i was doing wrong is that i should do sum = sum * num[i], thats all! Thanks For help all of you!

Comment: @FilipJava, **TIP** sum *= num[i]; is the same as sum = sum*num[i]; - it's just a quicker way of writing it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a LITTLE better, although there is still quite a bit of tidying up to do!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Program
{
class Third
{

    public static void Main()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Enter how many numbers");

        int howMuch = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int[] num = new int[howMuch];

        int sum = 1;
        for(int i=0;i<num.Length;i++) //allows you to fill the array
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Please enter an integer");
            sum *= int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // this will now multiply the value to sum, as your comment suggests
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sum);

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

}
}
```

**EDIT**

```
sum *= num[i];
```

should do what you want!

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to get input from user and fill the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
{
     //TODO: Look into int.TryParse method to validate user input
     num[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

And instead of overwriting `sum` use `sum += num[i] * num[i]` in your second loop. Or if you are looking for the multiplication of all numbers just use `sum = sum * num[i];` and start sum from `1`.

Comment: Judging from the OP's description, they wish to multiply every number together (or thats the way I read it.. i.e factorial)

Comment: @Sayse yeah that part is not clear to me either. I added that option too.

Comment: i don't know about it being factorial cause the OP has created an array? But totally agree that it's quite unclear what the OP's intentions are

Comment: Yes, i want every number what user input to be multiplied example:
userInput = 2, 3, 4
result = 2 * 3 * 4 = 24
And write that

Comment: You might not have enough rep to +1, but you DO have enough to accept a single answer (by clicking on the **tick** to the left of one) - it could help someone in the future as well if they happen to stumble across this

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not initialize the array - I added

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter number " + (i + 1));
        num[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

for that.

Also corrected the summarisation: `sum += ...`

```
for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++ )
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter number " + (i + 1));
    num[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    sum += (num[i] * num[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the math that you are doing in the loop.

```
sum = num[i] * num[i];
```

Each time through, you're setting sum equal to the square of the indexed integer.

Taking your example of 2, 3, 5, the first time through the loop, you will set sum = 2 * 2 (or 4), the second time through, you'll set sum = 3 * 3 (or 9) and the last time it will be sum = 5 * 5 (or 25).  What you really want is 2 * 3 * 5, right?

All you would need to do is to initialize `int sum = 1`, and change the statement in your loop to be:

```
sum = sum * num[i];
```

This will yield sum = 1 * 2 the first time through, sum = 2 * 3 the second time through, and sum = 4 * 5 the third time through.

Answer (score 0):

I've assumed that the sum that you want to do (if the input is 2,3,5) is 2*3*5. If this is the case, then naming your variable `sum` is a little misleading as that would tend to imply 2+3+5.

The `for` loop where you multiply the numbers had the line

```
sum = num[i]*num[i];
```

Which, following with the example, when i == 0, would do `sum = 2*2`, and then overwrite it as you increment the loop, so `sum` would end at being 25 (5*5), and discount all other values.

If you did want to sum the squares of the numbers, initializing `sum` to 0 and then using the line

```
sum += num[i] * num[i];
```

would work. Having said that, unless you specifically need to store it for any reason, processing the values when they are read would be better, as the program would have 1 fewer `for` loop.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Program
{
class Third
{

public static void Main()
{

    Console.WriteLine("Enter how much numbers");

    int howMuch = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    int[] num = new int[howMuch];
    for(int i = 0; i < howMuch; ++i)
    {
        //This is assuming that the user will enter an int value.
        //Ideally, verify this using int.TryParse or something similar.
        num[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    int sum = 1; //Set to 1 so that the PRODUCT is not always zero

    for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++ )
    {
        sum *= num[i]; //Multiply the value
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sum);

    Console.ReadLine();

}

}
```

If the input is 2, 3, 5, the value in sum will be 30

Answer (score -1):

replace the code in Main() with this :-

```
    Console.WriteLine("Enter how much numbers");

    int howMuch = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    int[] num = new int[howMuch];

    Console.WriteLine("Enter numbers");

    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++ )
    {
        num[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        sum += num[i] * num[i]; // this is what i did but it does not work?
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sum);

    Console.ReadLine();
```